# Set Theory - How do I solve this problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A={1,2,3,...,8,9} B={2,4,6,8} C={1,3,5,7,9} D={3,4,5} E={3,5}
Which of these sets can equal a set X under each of the following conditions?

a. X and B are disjoint

b. X is a subset of D but X is not a subset of B

c. X is a subset of  A but X is not a subset of C

d. X is a subset of  C but X is not a subset of A

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If X is a subset of any letter like A B C D E, then there are elements in X and there are elements in A B C D E. The elements have to be the same. At least that's what I read in my book last semester

Comment: Do you understand what the terms mean (ie subset, disjoint)? If not, what is your difficulty?

Comment: Well, just to be clear, $X$ and $B$ disjoint means that none of 2,4,6,8 can be in $X$. So which of $A,B,C,D,E$ satisfy that criterion?

Answer (score 0):

a. Any set X that does not contain an element of B (see definition of "disjoint").

b. Any set X that contains only elements of D, but contains an element not in B (see definition of "subset").

c. Analogous to b.

d. Analogous to b.

Answer (score 0):

For a., we need a set $X$ which contains elements that are **not** in $B$ which is what disjoint means. Now by considering all the different sets we can choose between, $C$ and $E$ seem like the only correct options, because all the other sets contain some element which is also in $B$. So the answer is $C$ and $E$

For b., we need a set which contains elements of $D$ (because it is a subset) and **not** elements of B. By consideration, we see $E$ is the only one which is a (proper) subset of $D$. But notice that $D$ is also a subset of $D$ itself. So the answer is $E$ and $D$.

Try to do the last two by yourself using the same reasoning.